# Adding url parameters in template using generic views in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-views, url-routing, django-1.5

I'm in the process of learning Django and currently I'm on a project following the [Polls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/) Tutorial loosely.

Now I'm trying to convert to generic views and this is where I'm running into problems:

**news/models.py**

```
[...]
class News(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200L)
  #rss_summary = models.CharField(max_length=2000L)
  rss_summary = models.TextField(max_length=2000L)
  #body_text = models.CharField(max_length=5000L)
  body_text = models.TextField(max_length=5000L)
  post_date = models.DateTimeField()
  class Meta:
      db_table = 'news'
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

**news/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from news import views
from news.models import News

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=News.objects.order_by('-post_date'),
            context_object_name='allnews',
            template_name='news/news.html'),
        name='news_index'),
[...]
```

**news/templates/news/news.html**

```
[...]
{% for item in allnews %}
  <h1 class="news"><a href="{% url 'news_index' item.id %}">{{item.title}}</a></h1>
  [...]
{% endfor %}
```

**Now my problem:** I'd like to link to a specific news item (via ID) using the `{% url 'foo' id %}` syntax using generic views like *ListView* or *DetailView*. How can I achieve this? I declared a name for the ListView, but I'm unable to figure out how to to specify the `allnews.id`.

With the code above I get the error

> NoReverseMatch at /news/ Reverse for 'news_index' with arguments
>   '(7L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

The funny thing is, "7L" is the id of the latest news item...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 2 views, one for the list and another for the details, so when you click on the item link in the list page, it will take you to the details view and template:

**news/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from news import views
from news.models import News

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=News.objects.order_by('-post_date'),
            context_object_name='allnews',
            template_name='news/news.html'),
        name='news_index'),

    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=News,
            context_object_name='item',
            template_name='news/news_item.html'),
        name='news_detail'),
[...]
```

**news/templates/news/news.html**

```
[...]
{% for item in allnews %}
  <h1 class="news"><a href="{% url 'news_detail' item.id %}">{{item.title}}</a></h1>
  [...]
{% endfor %}
```

**news/templates/news/news_item.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'news_index' %}">Back</a>

<h1 class="news">{{item.title}}</h1>
<p>{{ item.body_text }}</p>
```

Comment: This exactly covered and solved my problem. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong view for details. You defined `news_index` is a `ListView`, you need to implement `DetailView`. See more for [Urls in generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/#amend-urlconf) in django docs.

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=News,
            template_name='news/detail.html'),
        name='news_detail'),
```

and then in template

```
{% for item in allnews %}
  <h1 class="news"><a href="{% url 'news_detail' item.id %}">{{item.title}}</a></h1>
  [...]
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant: the URLconf for "^$" should refer to a view that shows all news as a list. This list should have html Links to the actual news like "/news/7". That's why I thought I'd use a ListView for the news "overview" and a DetailView for a single news item.